# Sidekiq Bugsnag Middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, bugsnag

Is there a way to integrate Bugsnag to rescue all exceptions for Sidekiq and send notifications? I can't find it in the docs.

```
def call(_worker, _msg, _queue)
Bugsnag.before_notify_callbacks << lambda do |notif|
  notif.add_tab(
    :gem_version,
    metascrape: Metascrape::VERSION
  )
end
yield
```

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
    Bugsnag.notify e
  ensure
    Bugsnag.before_notify_callbacks.clear
  end
end

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think you need to do anything?  The docs indicate it should just work.

> Bugsnag ruby works out of the box with Rails, Sidekiq, Resque, DelayedJob (3+), Mailman, Rake and Rack. It should be easy to add support for other frameworks, either by sending a pull request here or adding a hook to those projects.

https://bugsnag.com/docs/notifiers/ruby